# Active Directory Certificate Services - OCSP responder web proxy cache entries sync between nodes

Tags: active-directory, certificate, ocsp

I use Windows 2012 ADCS and I have a cluster of OCSP responders with 2 nodes.

The OCSP cluster share a single revocation configuration.

I have read into documentation that revocation configuration is synchronized between members of an Array but I cannot found in documentation or on Google if entries into the web proxy cache are also synchronized between members.

Is it the case ?

Answer (score 0):

I have performed a test and I have find a way to obtains a different validity status for a certificate in each web proxy cache of both OCSP nodes (OCSP node 1 = "valid", OCSP node 2 =  "revoked").

I have also wait around 2 hours to check if any sync occurs and the result was the same after this delay.

Conclusion on my test on Windows 2012 Active Directory Certificate Services OCSP module:

- Revocation configuration **is** shared and synchronized,
- Web proxy entries cache **is not** shared.
- Web proxy entries cache **is not** synchronized.